# Append a digit into an input HTML element via JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyboard-events

I am creating a calculator and need to append numbers by clicking on a div button, instead of typing on the keyboard.  But it must integrate with the use of the keyboard. Now, I know how to manipulate strings to achieve this, but positioning the blinking cursor at the end of the input element line escapes me...

Is there a way to call a keyboard event directly via a function call to emulate the key strokes, so that there is no manipulation of strings?

HTML input display markup...

```
    <div id="displayWindow" align="right">
        <input id="textInput" type="text" align-"right" value=""></input>
    </div>
```

And here is where I parse the incoming mouse event data:

```
function keyData(ev){
 var kee = ev.target.innerHTML;
 var nums = ".1234567890";
 if (nums.indexOf(kee)>=0){
    //Append value to number input display
    //  THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ....

 }
 var mathOps = "-+÷×±";
 if (mathOps.indexOf(kee)>=0){
    //Prepare math operations
 }
 var chars = "MC M+ M- MR";
 if (chars.indexOf(kee)>=0){
    //MEMORY handling functions
 }
 if (kee=="="){
    //Calculate
 }
 if (kee=="C"){
    //CLEAR everything
 }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated...

TIA

DK

Comment: indexOf returns -1 in case the kee is not found, what you want to use (I think) is `kee.indexOf(nums,kee) >= 0`

Comment: @Oliboy50 ... yes you are right...  I was speeding...  Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you set up a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what's going on ?

Comment: @adeneo  Hmmm demonstrating data entry via keyboard is not very inspiring since it would take only an input element. And the keyboard data entry part is what I am trying to figure out...

Comment: the `kee` is supposed to be a number (from the use of the `indexOf(nums,kee)`, but in your code we can see this `if(kee=="=")`, so what is it? your code is confusing on the thing you want to do.

Comment: Calculators have and equal sign used to sum or complete an addition, multiplication etc...  so when I click on that button, I detect it here...  I do not need help with that...   Look at this section... //  THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP ....

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```
    function simulateKeyPress(character) {
        $.event.trigger({ type : 'keypress', which : character.charCodeAt(0) });
    }
```

DK